# -webkit-line-clamp css not affecting in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Hi i have added css to show only particular no of lines but it is not affecting in Mozilla Firefox. Here is the css

```css
p.teknotrait1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 20px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 7 !important;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p class="teknotrait1">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: For mozilla use -moz-line-clamp: 7 !important;

Comment: `-webkit-` prefix is for webkit browsers (ex. chrome). For firefox use `-moz-` prefix

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp

Comment: @SudharsanS it is not accepting

Comment: this is not supported in mozilla fire fox

Comment: wrong there is no css equivalent to mozilla

Comment: then how can i show only n no of lines

Comment: @Ashalatha string manipulation

Comment: @madalinivascu i am not getting you

Comment: @Ashalatha you don't know what string manipulation is?

Comment: @madalinivascu just for adding y string manipulation is required i am asking that